# Can't send Email MS Exchange address via PHP

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I tried to send Email with using mail(). I can get emails on my Gmail account but
MS Exchange account doesn't get anything, even not as a spam mail.
I used the following code.
If someone tell me and how to successfully send email to exchange account, that would be great.
Thanks!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$Name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "test@gmail.com";
$msg = "Name: $Name\n" . "Email: $email\n" . "Message: $message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: If your getting mail at Gmail and not at what ever MS Exchange server you are using its getting blocked by the Exchange server or another service in front of that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I don't know how to check smtp logs yet, but as Christopher says it seems the Exchange server blocks them. Do you know how to not be blocked?

Comment: @user3011308 one example would be your sending from user@domain.com, if domain.com does not have a valid SPF record for your servers IP address then it is marking it as spam.  Tons of possibilities you will need to have the Exchange server admin check his logs and let you know whats up. The solution for that is to add a valid SPF record, or white list your servers IP address.

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher! I will dig into this more.

Comment: Did you found an answer to this question ?

Comment: @Zl3n After this, I found out I needed to use SMTP since some mail servers block emails coming from unreliable source. I would recommend to use PHPMailer with SMTP. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/sending-email-with-phpmailer-and-smtp